# MySQL Procedure check if record exists before insert not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, exists, not-exists

I have looked at the other questions on here about this. It isn't working.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `environment_admin`(
IN environment_id   TEXT,
IN user_id          TEXT,
IN username         VARCHAR(75),
IN password         VARCHAR(512)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE env_id INT;
DECLARE admin_id INT;

SET env_id = CAST(environment_id AS SIGNED INT);
SET admin_id = CAST(user_id AS SIGNED INT);

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `environment`.`environment_accounts` WHERE environment_id = env_id AND user_id = admin_id) THEN
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        `environment`.`environment_accounts` 
        (
            `environment_id`, 
            `user_id`, 
            `username`, 
            `password`, 
            `is_active`, 
            `is_admin`, 
            `is_mod`
        ) 
        VALUES 
        (
            env_id, 
            admin_id,
            username,
            password,
            1,
            1,
            1
        );
    END;
END IF;
END
```

So if I run:

```
CALL `environment`.`environment_admin`('22','1','kacieh','512c9ad228332bbd30d09ce7ffb8896e00a1610e914a5fa180bf15ce702b90423e6a9540579f672315ae3c6cb1b8d06ee2b784b4761e806675aa88c2a915553e');
```

I get 0 row(s) effected
and sure enough, nothing happened. -_- I have been working on this hours
I tested the conditional query, it works.
I have tested just the insert statement inside a stored proc, it works as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop doing it like that, it's inefficient and it could be worse if two insertare running concurrently! :)

Use INSERT.... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

One trick is to do ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE environment_id = env_id (not changing the column, so nothing will be updated, ensuring the INSERT will not work without any error condition, you might check number of modified/inserted rows after that)

Comment: but there can be many of the same environment_id's and many user_id's it is a many to many relationship. There will not be the same environment_id user_id combo though. I didn't make the pair the pk's though because I have other requirements that need those records to have a unique ID

Comment: this should work if I have a unique index on the combination of the two fields. I'll have to see if I have that or get that in there. Give me a few

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_environment_id_user ON environment ( environment_id, user_id);

Comment: yep I got the index created, and that is much, much better, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I realise you've solved your problem (and +1 for Parallelis's answer, especially for highlighting the concurrency issue), but just in case it helps someone else...

MySQL was probably getting confused between your parameters `environment_id` and `user_id` and the `environment_accounts` columns `environment_id` and `user_id`.  I suspect the parameters were taking precedence in the `WHERE` clause, meaning as long as there's at least one row in `environment_accounts`, the `NOT EXISTS` clause would always return false, and your insert would never run.

For example, if your `environment_id` and `user_id` parameters had values of 1 and 2 respectively, the `NOT EXISTS` clause would evaluate as

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `environment`.`environment_accounts` WHERE 1 = 1 AND 2 = 2) THEN
```

Might be worth having a naming convention for your parameters (and other variables), such as adding a prefix like `p_` for parameter.